# Get integer from a given string in C

Tags: c, integer, scanf, c-strings, fgets

I have a string of a Pokemon with some attributes like: Id, name, element, atk, defense, hp

```
1 Pikachu fire 10 6 30
```

Im getting this string from my file Pokemons.txt using fgets so every string has a pokemon

How do I get the integers to use in my battle function?

```
1
10
6
30
```

Comment: use the `strtok` to split it up string into array, separated by a space as a delimiter, that is assuming the format of the entire string contents in file is constant, then knowing the offset in the array, perform a `strtol` in each offset that is numeric.

Comment: Will there always be two words (e.g. "Pikachu fire") between the `1` and the `10`? Or could it also be one word or three words in some lines? Is "Pikachu" the "name" attribute and "fire" the "element" attribute?

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to do using standard C function `sscanf`. Let's assume that you already read a record from a file using `fgets` in a character array that as a result contains the following string

```
char s[] = "1 Pikachu fire 10 6 30\n";
```

Then you can write as shown below

```
#include <stdio,h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "1 Pikachu fire 10 6 30\n";

    unsigned int Id, atk, defense, hp;

    sscanf( s, "%u %*s %*s %u %u %u", &Id, &atk, &defense, &hp );

    printf( "Id = %u, atk = %u, defense = %u, hp = %u\n", Id, atk, defense, hp );
}
```

The program output is

```
Id = 1, atk = 10, defense = 6, hp = 30
```

The symbol `*` in format specifications like that `%*s` is an assignment-suppressing character.

Comment: Consider the good practice of checking the return value of `sscanf()`, especially for complex formats.

Answer (score 1):

[`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can be used to parse various data from strings.

Alternatively, [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) (and similar) for parsing just integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct monster {
    unsigned id;
    char name[64];
    char type[32];
    unsigned atk;
    unsigned def;
    unsigned hp;
};

static int parse_monster(struct monster *m, const char *dat)
{
    return 6 == sscanf(dat, "%u%63s%31s%u%u%u",
            &m->id, m->name, m->type, &m->atk, &m->def, &m->hp);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct monster mon = { 0 };

    if (parse_monster(&mon, "1 Pikachu fire 10 6 30"))
        printf("%s has %u hp.\n", mon.name, mon.hp);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Bad monster string.\n");
}
```

```
Pikachu has 30 hp.
```

Edge case: this will fail for monsters whose names contain a space (e.g., *"Mr. Mime"*), because `%s` ends when it reads whitespace. To avoid ambiguity, your *fields* should not contain your *delimiter*. Consider something more robust like [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Also dual-type monsters should be considered.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Type. I've clarified the answer.